# Get multiple products info in a single SOAP request (magento api)

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm trying to get products from Magento API with catalogProductList (soap v2) here is my function.

```
public function get_products() {
    $products = array();
    $login = $this->login_info();
    $proxy = new SoapClient($login['url']);
    $sessionId = $proxy->login($login['user'], $login['pass']);

    $result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);

    foreach($result as $value) {
        $products[] = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, $value->product_id);   
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($products);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

However because the request it's in a loop it will make for each product a request to Magento API.

I'm wondering if there is a solution to get multiple products info (based on provided product_id) in the same request. Maybe 50 or 100 products info for each request I think will reduce a lot the time of getting all the products.

I have found on http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

```
$params = array('filter' => array(
   array('key' => 'status', 'value' => 'pending'),
   array('key' => 'customer_is_guest', 'value' => '1')
));
$result = $client->salesOrderList($sessionId, $params);
```

but from my understanding it's more about filtering the products so I don't know if it helps too much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling the catalogProductList twice, first time outside the loop and the second time inside the loop passing invalid arguments, the doc [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html) is showing that you only need to use the method once passing the session id plus you are able to pass two extra optional arguments (array of filters and the store view id or code) additionally if the returned result catalogProductEntity is not enough you can override that part of the API adding extra product information for example the media images.

Comment: Can you give me a code example of what you mean ? Passing the catelogProductList twice was a typo mistake, and I've edited the post.